# JAXB not working with Quarkus native build - 'org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory not found'

Tags: gradle, jaxb, quarkus, quarkus-native

I'm building a microservice using Quarkus.
I'm using JAXB to marschall XML files that the service receives via a REST API endpoint.

My native build always throws the following error: `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory: Provider org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory not found`.
The error only occurs with the native build, the JVM build works fine.

In `build.gradle`, I added `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jaxb` and `org.glassfish.jaxb`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jaxb'
     .
     .
     .
    jaxb "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.1"
    jaxb "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.1"
}
```

Comment: You should only need `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jaxb`. What the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @geoand `DEBUG [io.ver.ext.web.RoutingContext] (executor-thread-1) RoutingContext failure (500): java.lang.RuntimeException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Error while searching for service [jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory]`
`with linked exception:
 [java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory: Provider org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory not found]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The following fixed it for me:

- Add org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-xml-jaxb as dependency to your build.gradle.
- Create a reflection-config.json (in folder src/main/resources) with the below content:

```
    [
      {
        "name": "org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory",
        "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
      }
    ]
```

- Reference the reflection config in your application.properties like so:

```
    quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json
```